Eleventy - Unable to find images on build
I am building a static blog using eleventy. I have my layouts set up but I'm having trouble getting the images to display. I'm using 11ty 3.0.0-alpha.10 with @11ty/eleventy-img version 4.0.2. I'm trying to use the transform method mentioned on the plugin page but I cannot get the path to the image file correct. When I try to build the site I get the error:
[11ty] 1. Having trouble writing to "./_site/blog/index.html" from "./content/blog.njk" (via EleventyTemplateError)
[11ty] 2. Transform `eleventy.htmlTransformer` encountered an error when transforming ./content/blog.njk. (via EleventyTransformError)
[11ty] 3. ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'content/images/flag-blur-unsplash.jpg' (via Error)
[11ty] 
[11ty] Original error stack trace: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'content/images/flag-blur-unsplash.jpg'

Here is how I am referencing the image in the layout
<img src="./images/flag-blur-unsplash.jpg" alt="" />

I have tried many different paths with no success.
This is how I set up the image plugin (same as what is on the plugin page):
eleventyConfig.addPlugin(eleventyImageTransformPlugin, {
    // which file extensions to process
    extensions: "html",

    // Add any other Image utility options here:

    // optional, output image formats
    formats: ["webp", "jpeg"],
    // formats: ["auto"],

    // optional, output image widths
    // widths: ["auto"],

    // optional, attributes assigned on <img> override these values.
    defaultAttributes: {
        loading: "lazy",
        decoding: "async",
    },
});

I tried configuring the plugin with different output options, but I ended up with the same error.
I want to have a layout with specific images referenced using a normal img tag and then have a blog post section with an image nested with the blog post. So some images will be in /public/images while others will be nested inside of /blog/posts/this-is-a-post. Both types of images will be displayed on the blog posts page and on the front page of the site, I just can't figure out how to reference them!
What can I try next?

This is probably just a generic thing for anyone who is out there searching for info on how to reference a basic image. I can reference the images inside an "img" folder:   <li><img src="img/filename.jpg" /></li>
Make sure you specify formats:
npx @11ty/eleventy --formats=html,gif,jpg,css  --serve
If you don't specify the format (jpg), it will not work.
